# Determine all eigenvalues of T

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and let $T \in B(X)$ be of the form
$$Tx=(x,\phi)\psi, \quad x \in X,$$
where $\phi,\psi \in X$.

The question is to determine all eigenvalues of $T$.
It has the following solution:

\begin{align}
Tx=\lambda x &\iff (x,\phi)\psi=\lambda x \\
&\iff \exists c \in \mathbb{K} : x =c\psi \\
&\iff \exists c \in \mathbb{K} : c(\psi,\phi)\psi = \lambda c \psi \\
&\iff (\psi,\phi)=\lambda
\end{align}

I don't see why this constant $c$ would exist. Can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: The second equivalence is not correct. The colinearity of $x$ and $\psi$ is not the only possibility. For the (to be checked that it is eigen)value $\lambda=0$ you have the solutions $x\in (\phi)^{\bot}$

Comment: The case you have computed (just putting arrows $\Leftarrow$) gives you the eigenvalue $\lambda=(\psi,\phi)$.

Comment: Okay... I'm just interested in the second line, though. Why does there exist a $c$ that satisfies $x=c\psi$?

Comment: Because if $\lambda \neq 0$, then $x=\frac{(x,\phi)}{\lambda}\psi$. So, $c=\frac{(x,\phi)}{\lambda}$ is such a $c$.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\neq 0$ and $x\neq\ker(T)$ (otherwise there is nothing to show) then 
$$Tx=\lambda x\Leftrightarrow \langle x,\phi\rangle\psi=\lambda x\Rightarrow \langle\langle x,\phi\rangle\psi,\phi\rangle=\langle\lambda x,\phi\rangle\Rightarrow\langle x,\phi\rangle\langle \psi,\phi\rangle=\lambda\langle x,\phi\rangle$$
Therefore we have 
$$\langle x,\phi\rangle\langle \psi,\phi\rangle-\lambda\langle x,\phi\rangle=0\Leftrightarrow \langle x,\phi\rangle(\langle \psi,\phi\rangle-\lambda)=0\Rightarrow \langle \psi,\phi\rangle=\lambda$$